# How could we prove "there exists" a linear transform that converts convolution to multiplication?

Tags: abstract-algebra, convolution

Let's pretend the Fourier transform was never invented.

Well, how could we prove *there exists* a linear transform $L$ over complex numbers such that, for two convolved integrable functions $f*g$, that $L[(f*g)(t)] = k \cdot L(f)L(g)$ for some normalization constant $k$?

I don't know much about abstract algebra, but this almost looks like the definition I see of a homomorphism. Are there circumstances under which we can ignore $k$?

Comment: It's not really clear what you are asking. Generally speaking, the way things are proved to exist is by constructing them. So we could pretend it was never invented but in case I would simply say we could prove it exists by inventing it all over again.

Comment: I don't see why it's unclear. If we didn't know the Fourier transform existed, how could we prove *some* linear transform, in general, does exist, satisfying this property?

Comment: In theory, we could show that the set of (sufficiently integrable) functions forms a ring under multiplication and also forms a ring under convolution; then if we could show those two rings were isomorphic, we could conclude that an isomorphism $L$ existed.

Comment: Such a linear transform, if it exists, is also Frechet differentiable. Could we conclude from this linearity property that is Frechet derivative exists?

Comment: The real interesting question is, why would one expect there is such a map? Showing that there actually is one is a minor point.

Comment: Your questions rings in me the historical fact that convolution is a very late "character" in Analysis. A certain number of convolutional integrals had been found until Hilbert had the idea to give a name to the associated operation ("faltung") at the beginning of the 20th century. The fact that it was a "noble" operation worth of interest took some decades ; for example, the translation of "faltung" into "convolution" appeared in English (and French) in the 1930s https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1348361/305862.

Comment: [Ctd] It was also in these years that the Fourier Transform (with its convolutional property) was discovered by Norbert Wiener.

Answer (score 4):

I don't know the precise answer off the top of my head and it quickly gets quite advanced but there is basically a whole theory of this in abstract harmonic analysis. The Fourier transform is a type of Gelfand representation.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gelfand_representation#Examples

We start with the algebra $A = L^1(\mathbf{C})$, where the algebra multiplication is convolution and let $\Phi$ denote the space of all multiplicative linear functionals on $A$, i.e. algebra homomorphisms $\phi : L^1(\mathbf{C}) \to \mathbf{C}$. Then for $f \in L^1(\mathbf{C})$ we can define $\tilde{f} : \Phi \to \mathbf{C}$ by $$ \tilde{f}(\phi) = \phi(f).$$

So the association $f \mapsto \tilde{f}$ defines a  map $L^1(G) \to $ {some space of functions on $\Phi$}.

So I guess (now someone will have to correct me if I'm wrong), the point is that you can show this is an algebra homomorphism to $C_0(\Phi)$ *and* that actually $\Phi \simeq \mathbf{C}$.

Comment: I don't know that I'm understanding this correctly, so if we consider the convolution over the space of $L_1$ functions, does the convolution turn $L_1$ into a Banach algebra? Or how do we interpret the Gelfand representation for this purpose?

Comment: @askquestions2 Yes, $L^1(\Bbb R)$ is a Banach algebra (with convolution for multiplication); in fact the Gelfand transform on that algebra is precisely the Fourier transform

Comment: Can you expand more on how you're actually using Gelfand representation to answer the question? It's not immediately clear to me since I'm not experienced in abstract algebra.

Comment: I tried to add some explanation but as I said, I can't remember this stuff very well so perhaps someone will explain more fully

Comment: Functionals map functions to scalar quantities, but convolutions map two functions to another function. What am I missing?

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking; both of those statements are correct.

Comment: Why are we concerned about the space of functionals when convolutions and the Fourier transform both map functions to functions, not functions to scalar quantities? Functionals seems irrelevant.